# from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer でなぜTokenizerを読み込めるのか分かりません

Tags: python, tensorflow

言語処理を勉強中のものです。
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/_api/v1/keras/preprocessing/text/
には

```
__init__.py  __pycache__
```

しかなく、__init__.pyの中身にも

```
# This file is MACHINE GENERATED! Do not edit.
# Generated by: tensorflow/python/tools/api/generator/create_python_api.py script.
"""Utilities for text input preprocessing.

"""

from __future__ import print_function

from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.text import hashing_trick
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.text import one_hot
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.text import text_to_word_sequence

del print_function
```

とTokenizerのモジュールの定義がないのに、なぜ

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
```

とすることでTokenizerが使えるようになるのでしょうか。Tokenizerの定義はどこに書いてあるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/preprocessing/`に`text.py`がありませんか？

[参考]
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/preprocessing/text.py

もしくは`/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages`ではないディレクトリ（例えば、`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`とか）にあるのではないですかね？

もしそれも違っていれば、以下のコマンドで探してみてはどうでしょう。

```sh
sudo updatedb
locate tensorflow/python/keras/preprocessing/text.py
```

Comment: おっしゃる通り `text.py` が見つかりました。
最初から`/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/_api/v1/keras/preprocessing/text/__init__.py`に Tokenizer などの定義を書けばいい気がするのですが、なぜ「迂回」するようなディレクトリ構成になっているのでしょうか？

Comment: Pythonのimportの仕様について少し勉強してみると、なぜその`text.py`を参照しているのか分かると思います。

Comment: `__init__.py`のコードによって、なぜこの`text.py`を参照しているのかは分かりましたが、なぜこのようなディレクトリ構成になっているのでしょうか？

Comment: 疑問に思われた点が、私にはよく理解できませんでした。この質問はクローズしているので、疑問点を明確にした上で改めて質問を投稿いただいた方がいいかもしれません。その方が他の人からも回答がもらいやすいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

以下↓↓、コメント誤りです。パッケージの理解が、おかしかったです。申し訳ございません。

（もしかすると回答になっていないかもしれませんが。）
Tokenizerは、モジュールではないです。

以下などが、参考になるのでは？
https://qiita.com/enoughspacefor/items/051b219ff403ef9a4ed5